# No input file specified error. Codeigniter 3 and go daddy subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am getting following error after opening the codeigniter base url:
"No Input file specified". I know that it has something to do with htaccess file but can't make it work.

my htaccess file content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Go daddy directory structure: htaccess file is at root folder of subdomain.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess file is fine you need to check paths in controller
i guess it could be view file missing

```
$this->load->view('file_view', $data);
```

in views folder it is named "file_view.php"

also make sure file paths are correct
if you are calling a module module file exists under modules folder

check `$route['default_controller'] = "frontpage";` in routs.php under config folder for above line frontpage.php must exist in views folder

add rewrite base

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: default controller is already set to Admin controller which is correct. Views and Models are also present as everything is working on localhost.

Comment: on live server try to access site site.com/index.php and without index.php if it gets loaded also make sure mod rewrite is set to enabled in php.ini

Comment: try with 
RewriteBase /

Comment: Thanks. If i try with RewriteBase, i get a different error:Type: RuntimeException

Message: Unable to locate the model you have specified: Admin_model

Filename: /home/meshicreations/public_html/meshilabel/system/core/Loader.php

Line Number: 344

Backtrace:

File: /home/meshicreations/public_html/meshilabel/application/controllers/Admin.php
Line: 29
Function: model

File: /home/meshicreations/public_html/meshilabel/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: Please note, views, models and controller are present and there path is also correct.

Comment: your rewrite base is RewriteBase /meshilbel or RewriteBase /meshilbel/ correct ?